# Trouble sending a large file using sockets in c

Tags: c, sockets, webserver

So I'm working on writing a simple web server in C, and now I'm trying to figure out how to transfer larger files.  I'm trying to do it with a file ~40MB right now and I'm getting a segmentation fault (at least that's what wget tells me!)

The thing is, the program itself never actually gives me an error, it just quits out, it's only when I try and get the file using wget that wget says that it errors in a seg fault.  Here's the code that sends the file:

```
while( 1 ) {
  int bytes_read = fread( file_buffer, 1, BUFFER_SIZE, f );
  printf( "Bytes read: %d\n", i * 1024 );
  if ( bytes_read == 0 ) {
    if ( logging > 0 ) {
      printf( "End of file reached...\n" );
    }
    break;
  } else {
    send( client, file_buffer, strlen( file_buffer ), 0 );
if ( logging > 1 ) {
      printf( "Buffer (%d): %s\n\n", bytes_read, file_buffer );
    }
  }
  i++;
}
```

Any ideas what's going wrong?  It works fine with smaller files, just not this one.  Oh, and the bytes read varies each time I try, it gets anywhere from 240000 to 770000.  Thoughts?  Thanks!

Comment: Well, for one, you can't use strlen on a binary stream -- it will stop at the first 0 byte.  Is there a reason you're not using bytes_read in your send call?

Answer (score 1):

fread doesn't null terminate strings.  You need to use bytes_read as the length parameter to send, not strlen.

You also either need to null-terminate the string before trying to print it, or provide a length with the %s formatter.  For example: printf( "Buffer (%d): %.*s\n\n", bytes_read, bytes_read, file_buffer );

Comment: Hey, I've made these corrections still to no avail.  I've also tried commenting out all of the print lines.  Could it be an available memory issue?

Comment: Seriously doubt it.  Show us more code, especially the declarations and initializations of file_buffer and BUFFER_SIZE.  Also, fread() returns size_t, not int, and you mention that this failure occurs with large files.  Remember that size_t is not the same size as int on many platforms.   What OS and compiler are you using and what bit size are you compiling for?

Answer (score 1):

You shouldn't use strlen(file_buffer) to specify how many bytes to send; this will break in many circumstances, and will always break when the file sent is bigger than your buffer.  Why not just use bytes_read to specify how many bytes to send?

Comment: Oops, sorry, that was a mistake definitely as I upgraded from an older version of my code.  I changed it to bytes_read and the problem still persists though?

Comment: @Pete.Mertz: Your problem still persists because you're trying to print file_buffer as a null-terminated string and it is not a null-terminated string.  See the edits I added to my answer on how to fix that.